# Connection issue with Spring boot 3.2 and Google Cloud Mysql

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm working on transitioning to Google Cloud MySQL. We are currently connected to our own managed mysql server and it is working fine. We are using four separate MySql connections so the setup is not straightforward. Here are my changes specifically for Google Cloud MySQL

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
    ....
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 .....
  </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
           <version>5.0.0</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

application.properties:

```
    spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=PROJECT_ID
    spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:CREDENTIAL_FILE_LOCATION
    spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=false
    
    userdb.read.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:///DB_NAME?cloudSqlInstance=INSTANCE_NAME&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
    userdb.read.datasource.username=USERNAME
    userdb.read.datasource.password=PASSWORD   
    userdb.read.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=5000
    userdb.read.datasource.tomcat.max-active=2
    userdb.read.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
    # THREE MORE SIMILAR CONNECTION SETTINGS
```

I have configured the credentials in addition to the connection settings. The rest of my code is as is, what do you think I'm doing wrong? Below is the error I'm getting:

```
: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:111) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:995) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:809) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:440) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:8.1.0

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.getCredentials(ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.java:42) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.java:32) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.apiFetcher(CoreSocketFactory.java:417) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.lambda$getCloudSqlInstance$0(CoreSocketFactory.java:396) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[?:?]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:127) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:129) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:101) ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.getCredentials(ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.java:40) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.java:32) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.apiFetcher(CoreSocketFactory.java:417) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory.lambda$getCloudSqlInstance$0(CoreSocketFactory.java:396) ~[jdbc-socket-factory-core-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: The error message does tell you what's wrong and directs you to read a GCP documentation how to resolve it. Have you read the documentation and tried to implement what it says?

Comment: Yes, it is asking to create credential file, which has been created and set in the properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending many hours, the solution turns out to be very simple. Adding it here in case some folks run into the similar issue. I was using `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location` property to set the credentials but the [google cloud sql connection factory library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc.md) doesn't care about that. We need to use `gcloud auth application-default login` command to create and credential and gcloud command saves it in your folder: /Users/your_user_name/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json . The spring boot app automatically picks it up, not need to set it using with spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location file.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to do it. Also the other methods such as setting env variable should also work, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you are trying to use the Cloud SQL Java Connector (cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) to connect to the SQL instances. The Java Connector calls GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault() to get the Google credential. According to the [API doc](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials), this API searches the credential file in this order,

> 1. Credentials file pointed to by the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable
> 2. Credentials provided by the Google Cloud SDK.

> - gcloud auth application-default login for user account credentials.
> - gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account for impersonated service account credentials.
> - Google App Engine built-in credentials
> - Google Cloud Shell built-in credentials
> - Google Compute Engine built-in credentials

which doesn't seem to include the Spring boot's application.properties. Maybe you can try using one of the methods above?

Comment: Hi Anna, I have set up the credentials using spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location property, does this not work? Also I have to set spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled= false, because I'm creating datasources myself, will that impact the credentials setup? Is there a way rather than specifiying the credentials in the properties file, I can specify programmatically?

Comment: Specifying the credetnial file location in spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location won't work because GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault() has not context of that. One quick way to check if my theory holds may be set up the environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" pointing to the credential file?